# Using JavaScript in Ionic 2

Tags: javascript, ionic2

I have several JavaScript files (e.g., myFunctions.js). Where do I need to specify information about this file and how can I use it in a .html page? For example, if myFunctions.js contains a function called myFunction1, what do I need to do to be able to call myFunction1 in myPage.html that has myPage.ts and myPage.sccs files?

I DO NOT want to recode the JavaScript as a TypeScript file and am looking for a way to use "legacy" code.

Comment: Just add exports to the js file and import them in your appropriate typescript. All javascript is valid typescript.

Comment: When you say add exports, do you mean to add "exports.fn=fn" if there is a "function fn(...){...}" or change this to "module.exports=function fn(...){...}" or something else?
When you say import into typescript do you mean to use something like "import {MyJS} from './MyJS'" or "import * as myJS from './MyJS'" or something else?
Please be specific.

Comment: All of those options are valid, it's hard to suggest without knowing specifically what your code looks like and what you want to do. Pick one, try it, see if you like it.

Comment: I am trying to use a "legacy" JavaScript file and I still don't know where it should be stored and what modifications are required to other files to use it in an html file. Any suggestions? Are there any demos, examples, articles, etc. that show what is required? What my code looks like is unimportant. Assume I am starting a new project and want to create a page that uses a JavaScript file. What would I need to do?

Comment: If you're starting a new project: create a javascript file in your project (`touch file.js`, `export function doThings = () => {}`, then `import { doThings } from './file'`.